# Passing in a user-defined variable value for maven from the command lne

Tags: java, maven, variables, command-line

I'm working on a build script to compile a WAR using maven. I want to be able to pass in certain values like the version number from the command line when I run the maven command. After some research I found that you can pass in values using a -D flag. I thought I had it figured out, but something is not quite working. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>This is an app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <db.password>$db_pwd</db.password>
        <email.key>$email_key</email.key>
        <modo.api.token>$modo_api_token</modo.api.token>
        <modo.auth.shared>$modo_auth_shared</modo.auth.shared>
        <build.version>$build_version</build.version>
    </properties>
    <version>${build.version}</version>
...
```

I then execute the compile with the command

> mvn clean package -Dbuild_version=0.0.2-SNAPSHOT

For some reason, the variable replacement doesn't work. I end up with a WAR file named myapp-$build_version.war instead of myapp-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war . I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to put `${build_version}` not `$build_version`

Comment: The same apply for the other properties (eg: `${db_pwd}` not `$db_pwd`).